# How can I write a pseudocode for this scenario?

Tags: pseudocode

How can I write a pseudocode for this?

Gross pay depends on the pay rate and the number of hours worked per week. However, if you work more than 40 hours, you get paid time-and-a-half for all hours worked over Write the pseudo-code to compute gross pay given pay rate and hours worked.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly pseudocode is can be interpreted in different ways for different people. If I were to write this, I would say something like:

```
function calculate_gross_pay(dollars_per_hour: number, hours: number)
    if hours > 40
        base_pay = 40 * dollars_per_hour
        overtime_pay = (hours - 40) * (dollars_per_hour * 1.5)
        gross_pay = base_pay + overtime_pay
        return gross_pay
    else
        return hours * dollars_per_hour
```

Comment: thanks for a recommendation :) it helped me to understand Pseudocode better!

Comment: No problem—it's useful to remember that there's no "right" way to write pseudocode, so just write what you think will allow others to understand the logic of your code.

Comment: Also if this answered your question I'd appreciate it if you mark my answer as resolved :)